# How to get the checkbox value inside splittbutton from c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, extjs, ext.net

I have a problem with something in EXT.NET.  I have the next structure in EXT.NET

```
<ext:SplitButton runat="server" ID="btnExcel" Icon="PageExcel" ToolTip="Something text" Cls="ReportesButton" OverCls="ReportesButtonOver">
        <Bin>
            <ext:Menu runat="server" ID="Menu3">
                <Items>
                    <ext:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel17" Width="180" Height="25" Layout="VBoxLayout">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:Checkbox runat="server" ID="chkbox" Checked="false" IndicatorText="Something text">
                                <Listeners>
                                    <Change Handler="#{btnExcel}.bin[0].hide();"></Change>
                                </Listeners>
                            </ext:Checkbox>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:Panel>
                </Items>
            </ext:Menu>
        </Bin>
        <Listeners>
            <ArrowClick Handler="this.bin[0].show(); this.bin[0].alignTo(this.el);"></ArrowClick>
        </Listeners>
</ext:SplitButton>
```

Until this moment, everything is  fine, but when I try to get the value in my .cs class using chkbox.Checked or chkbox.Value all the time the value is false, even when I change the checkbox value.  I never had problems with chkbox.Checked using checkbox from another way.  I would appreciate some help.  I use EXT.NET 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extraparameter could be a option, but what I did was to change the control and the structure of this way:

```
<ext:SplitButton runat="server" ID="btnExcel" Icon="PageExcel" ToolTip="Something Text" Cls="ReportesButton" OverCls="ReportesButtonOver">
    <Bin>
        <ext:Menu runat="server" ID="Menu3">
            <Items>      
                <ext:CheckMenuItem ID="chkbox" runat="server" Text="Something Text" Checked="false">
                    <Listeners>
                        <Click Handler="#{btnExcel}.bin[0].hide();"></Click>
                    </Listeners>
                </ext:CheckMenuItem>                                              
            </Items>
        </ext:Menu>
    </Bin>
    <Listeners>
        <ArrowClick Handler="this.bin[0].show(); this.bin[0].alignTo(this.el);"></ArrowClick>
    </Listeners>
</ext:SplitButton>
```

I think the structure have to work with a specific control to run fine

Answer (score 0):

Code behind will only see values the page had initially (as long as defined in markup, not from other code behind calls like `Page_Load()`) unless you have submitted the values somehow. Ext.NET just does not submit back everything every time you call a code behind, so the problem is not necessarily in the code snippet you provided or shown, but the way you are calling the code behind.

Usually form fields in a formPanel are submitted on code behind calls, but it depends on how you are calling code behind.

In your case you probably need to pass the checkbox's current value using an **ExtraParameter** in the direct event/method call. But really, it depends how you are calling code behind.

For a DirectEvent-handled button passing the checkbox value, it would be:

```
<ext:Button runat="server" Text="Check">
    <DirectEvents>
        <Click OnEvent="CheckCheckBoxValue">
            <ExtraParams>
                <ext:Parameter
                    Name="name"
                    Value="App.Panel17.down('checkbox').getValue()"
                    Mode="Raw"
                    />
            </ExtraParams>
        </Click>
    </DirectEvents>
</ext:Button>
```

Code snippet based on [DirectEvents - WebService example](http://examples4.ext.net/#/Events/DirectEvents/WebService/)